# Home Assistant Can't Extract Data from Python/JSON MQTT Message

Tags: python, jinja2, mqtt, home-assistant

I'm sending JSON data from a python script to Home Assistant. HA receives the data but I cannot get my template to read it correctly. I can't see what I'm missing – I want to access the temperature and humidity properties in the JSON.

**Python Client Publish Script** *(Python 2.7.16)*

```py
msg_json = {
  "climate": {
    "temperature": str(temperature_f),
    "humidity": str(humidity_f)
  }
}
result = client.publish(topic, payload=json.dumps(msg_json))
status = result[0]
print("Send {0} to topic {1}").format(msg_json, topic)

// OUTPUT -> Send {'climate': {'temperature': '9', 'humidity': '7'}} to topic rpi3/sensors/climate
```

**HA configuration.yaml**

```
    - platform: mqtt
      state_topic: 'rpi3/sensors/climate'
      name: 'RPi3 Climate'
      value_template: '{{ value_json.climate }}'
```

**HA Dev Template**

```
Data: {{ states('sensor.rpi3_climate') }} 
    -> OUTPUTS: Data: {'temperature': '9', 'humidity': '7'}

Temperature: {{ state_attr('sensor.rpi3_climate', "temperature") }}
    -> OUTPUTS: Temperature: None
```

**HA Dev Template Alternative**

```
{% set temp = states("sensor.rpi3_climate") %}
{% set climate_json = temp|to_json %}
The temperature is: {{ climate_json }}
    -> OUTPUTS: The temperature is: "{'temperature': '9', 'humidity': '7'}"

The temperature is: {{ climate_json.temperature }} 
    -> OUTPUTS: The temperature is:
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so to answer my own question... I came up with what I think is a work around but I'm sure I've missed something and should be able to access the data being sent in it's original format.

I changed the format of the JSON message being sent:

```py
msg_json = {
   "temperature": str(temperature_f),
   "humidity": str(humidity_f)
}
```

and edited my `configuration.yaml` so that humidity and temperature had they're own entity:

```
    - platform: mqtt
      state_topic: 'rpi3/sensors/climate'
      name: 'RPi3 Climate'

    - platform: mqtt
      state_topic: 'rpi3/sensors/climate'
      name: 'RPi3 Temperature'
      value_template: '{{ value_json.temperature }}'

    - platform: mqtt
      state_topic: 'rpi3/sensors/climate'
      name: 'RPi3 Humidity'
      value_template: '{{ value_json.humidity }}'
```

I was then able to create a card using that sensor's data.